# missing post from {page-id}/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

assume you have a post whose id is XXX

then,

visit `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/XXX?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`, you can see the post

but

this post is missing from

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/feed?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`

i am pretty sure this post is published and is not hidden (by checking the field `is_published` and `is_hidden`)

i am wondering why i can not fetch this post by {page-id}/feed

the post id i am talking about is `86398004596_10155126493894597` published at 2017-07-01T07:22:36+0000

you can easily reproduce it as long as you have a page access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/86398004596_10155126493894597?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/86398004596/feed?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`

Comment: Perhaps the user turned of Facebook's integration with apps: https://www.facebook.com/help/211829542181913

Comment: if the user turned off Facebook's integration with apps, why only some posts missing from the feed?

Comment: So you see other posts of this user in the feed?

Comment: yes, but some of the posts are missing for the feed. weird

Comment: Perhaps it is this "bug" https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677415322538919/ or a new one ...

Comment: totally make sense. thanks!